# Conditions for passing limit inside a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider a succession $\{f_{n,k}\}_{n,k}$ s.t. for any fixed $k$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n,k}=g_k$.
Which are the conditions s.t.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k}f_{n,k}=\sum_{k}g_k \; \;?
\end{equation}